# Can we ship an iOS app not fully but with only base features so then users can download additional modules instead of we just enabling/disabling them?

Tags: ios, swift

So the whole idea is for the app to be as minimum in size as it can get.
The app will have different features based on what users paid and I don’t want an user to download the app with all the features on it so then we check on backend which features he has paid and hide/disable other features but instead I want the app primary to have the base modules and then checking on backend what additional features he has paid and so the app would download these modules/features automatically from appstore and show them on app. Android has something like dynamic features where they can download specific modules from playstore and not the whole app and I was wondering if this can also be possible in iOS. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DardanAr, you need to ask questions with code, not to ask if it is possible. Because it is on all type of program languages. Please, write some code and share with us to help you understand the code and then you can evolve with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think I was very clear. Right now I don't have the code because that's why I asked in first place because I want to develop the app which is now just an idea and I was asking if that's possible. And didn't see any rule here stating that I can't make questions without code!

Comment: As @Gereon write, do it in your own code. Other words is, make your own toggle.

Answer (score 2):

From the review guidelines:

> 2.5.2 Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, nor may they download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes features or functionality of the app, including other apps.

TL;DR: No.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.. really appreciate it!
But how does Facebook, Instagram etc change functionality without us updating the app or they use react-native which allows them?

Comment: How do you know they're not simply using feature toggles in their existing code?

Comment: yes I agree it's highly possible to be that, but I was just asking because I have a phone which I hadn't touch in years and when I checked there is the new UI which is now available on latest versions and I was wondering if that UI design is made since then or  they use something else!

Comment: UI can be expressed with things like HTML and CSS, there's no restriction against that in the rule.